# Reshaping Data from Long to Wide by Group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, tidyr

I have a data set that has been giving me some trouble. I did not think it would turn into such a complex problem, but now I feel like it has.

I have a data set that looks somewhat similar to this

```
CaseInfoColNames   CaseInfoData  UID  RunTime 
**WarrantCase**    XXXXXXXXXXXX  P19  TIME
Desc               .             P19  TIME 
Bond               500           P19  TIME
Remarks            No License    P19  TIME 
**WarrantCase**    YYYYYYYYYYYY  P19  TIME
Desc               .             P19  TIME
Bond               200           P19  TIME 
**CaseNumber**     123456789134  X20  TIME
Desc               BOND          X20  TIME 
Bond               1000          X20  TIME
CommentCase        DIV 2         X20  TIME
Charge             Drive w.o.Lic X20  TIME
```

Basically, there are IDs and for each ID there can be two types either a "Warrant Case" or a "Case Number." The rows that follow beneath these two headings should become the column headers. Each ID could have multiple rows and I am realizing that some column headers will not be the same, so is there a way to  fill in NAs too. Idealistically, maybe the data could look something like this, but if this is too much of a hassle maybe it is better to leave in the long format? Many thanks!

```
UID  RunTime WarrantCase  Desc Bond Remarks 
P19  TIME    XXXXXXXXXXXX  .    500 No License
P19  TIME    YYYYYYYYYYYY  .    200  NA
X20  TIME    NA           BOND  1000 NA

CaseNumber CommentCase Charge     
  NA         NA           NA
  NA         NA           NA    
  123..    DIV 2          Drive w.o. Lic
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to create a unique ID for each case so that all the lines from each case have the same ID:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(caseID = cumsum(as.numeric(grepl("\\*\\*",df1$CaseInfoColNames)))) %>% 
  spread(CaseInfoColNames,CaseInfoData)

 UID RunTime caseID **CaseNumber** **WarrantCase** Bond        Charge CommentCase Desc    Remarks
1 P19    TIME      1           <NA>    XXXXXXXXXXXX  500          <NA>        <NA>    . No.License
2 P19    TIME      2           <NA>    YYYYYYYYYYYY  200          <NA>        <NA>    .       <NA>
3 X20    TIME      3   123456789134            <NA> 1000 Drive.w.o.Lic       DIV.2 BOND       <NA>
```

You can remove the caseID column later if you want